Getting error while trying to import jwt-decode
I am getting error "Cannot find module 'jwt-decode' or its corresponding type declarations."
But I imported the jwt_decode
like this:
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
And installed jwt_decode using these commands:
npm install --save @types/jwt-decode
npm install --save jwt-decode
But it didn't help.
Do I need to add something in app.module.ts?

I solved problem updating node.js to the latest version, and by updating my workspace and its dependencies using "ng update"

The library provides its own types, so installing @types/jwt-decode is incorrect and only contains a stub types definition.
In addition, the library is called jwt-decode (ensure you don't install jwt_decode as written in your question).
The function jwtDecode is exported using ES modules, so the usage should be:
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

// For reference:
[Module: null prototype] {
  InvalidTokenError: [class InvalidTokenError extends Error],
  jwtDecode: [Function: jwtDecode]
}


I solved problem updating node.js to the latest version, and by updating my workspace and its dependencies.
